# Cannot add JUnit 5 Test Case

Tags: eclipse, maven, selenium, junit5

I'm setting up a new project in  my coworker's PC in his Eclipse, so we can use Selenium and JUnit 5.4 and Maven, the problem is that option **New JUnit Juniper Test** does not appear when creating a new JUnit Test Case. I'm using JUnit 5.4 and here is my screen when I try to create a new JUnit test case:

[image]

This option above does not appear to him. Our **pom.xml** looks exactly the same, here is our **pom.xml**:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>XXX</groupId>
    <artifactId>XXX</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And here is my Java Build Path:

[image]

I don't have JUnit 5 library added, but when I try to add, at least JUnit 5 library appears for me to add, and for him it only has versions 3 and 4 to add libraries.

[image]

In his PC, only the first 2 options **New JUnit 3 test** and **New JUnit 4 test** appear, what am I missing?

Comment: He is probably using an outdated version of Eclipse without JUnit 5 support.

Comment: hmm I believe the eclipse version was the only thing I did not check, good point, I'll take a look and update here in case that's the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing *New JUnit Juniper Test* option in the *New JUnit Test Case* dialog means that you are using an outdated **Eclipse version Oxygen.1 (4.7.1) or lower**.

See: [Eclipse Project Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a) - New and Noteworthy - Eclipse support for JUnit 5](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.7.1a/#junit-5-support)